# Value of the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x|\cos(nx)dx$ when $n$ odd,even

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Value of the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x|\cos(nx)dx$ when $n$ odd,even

While solving the problem I was stuck at a point

$\int_{0}^{\pi} x\cos(nx)dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi - x)\cos(n(\pi-x))dx$

Or is it

$\int_{0}^{\pi} x\cos(nx)dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi - x)\cos((\pi-nx))dx$

Comment: It should definitely be $n(\pi-x).$ You are substituting $t=\pi-x$ in an integral, so $x=\pi-t$ and $nx=n(\pi-t).$ I don't see how this substitution helps you solve your integral, though.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx.$$

In your case, $a=0, b=a+b=\pi,$ and $f(x)=x\cos(nx).$ So $$f(a+b-x)=f(\pi-x)=(\pi-x)\cos(n(\pi-x)).$$

But $\cos(n(\pi-x))=(-1)^n\cos(nx).$ So you get:

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\pi x\cos(nx)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}(-1)^n(\pi-x)\cos(nx)\,dx\end{align}$$

When $n$ is even, we can add these two together to get:

$$2I=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)\,dx$$

This gives $I=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ when $n=0$ and $I=0$ for other even $n.$

But I don't know how this helps to solve the $n$ odd case.

It's definitely easier to use integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, integrate by parts
\begin{align}
I_n=&\int_{0}^{\pi} x\cos(nx)dx\\
= &\ \frac1n \int_{0}^{\pi} x\ d(\sin nx)
= - \frac1n \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin nx\ dx
=\frac{\cos n\pi -1}{n^2}
\end{align}
Thus, $I_{2m}=0$ and $I_{2m+1}=-\frac2{(2m+1)^2}$.

Comment: Special case for $n=0,$ of course.